# Как настроить подсветку синтаксиса в IPython?

Tags: python, ipython

Подсвечивается только синтаксис при выводе. Как включить подсветку при вводе команд?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы про ipython или всё же про ipython-notebook (ныне Jupyter)?

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev про IPython

Comment: В таком случае не очень понятно, что значит "синтаксис подсвечивается при выводе". Думаю, лучше привести изображения и подробнее описать то, что вы хотите получить

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev да, подсвечивается просто вывод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с версии 5.0 IPython поддерживает подсветку синтаксиса непосредственно при вводе кода.